# How can I add dynamic referances in compile resources?

Tags: xcode, xcode-build-phase

I have a Python script that generates various ".swift" files. I also have "Build-Phases" such that resources.py generates different ".swift" files in the same folder

Build Phase look like this:

[image]

I've created a .xcfilelist file, and when the script runs, I write the file names into the .xcfilelist. The .xcfilelist looks like this:

[image]

Afterwards, I've added the Output Files in the build phases script. It looks like:

[image]

When the script finishes running, files should be added to the compile resources, but they are not being included properly.

Where i do mistake? How can i add files in to compile resources?

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. Any help will highly appreciated